# What is the preferred / common way to separate "access-tokens" in a database design

Tags: database-design, mariadb

I'm currently having a case where a user has to verify their email, is able to reset his password and can log into a web-interface (so far and not limited to). There a now 3 places where some kind of token is used to give a user access to a specific action.

1. **Web session** - Access token used to access API endpoints.
2. **Email verification** - Access token used to verify a (new) email-address.
3. **Password reset** - Access token used to change a password.

So far I've come up with two possible solutions:

#### a) A separate table for each token:

There will be a `web_session`, `email_verified` and `password_reset` table.

Pros:

- Each table can come with meta-unique properties
- You can easily grab data from on of these tables based on their name

Cons:

- All tables are kinda related but have very different names (and I couldn't come up with a naming-way to "group" them)
- Almost all columns are equal across these tables (`id`, `user_id`, `token`, `created_at`)
- Every time something like this gets added I'd have to create a seperate table with (always / almost?!) the same columns.

#### b) A unified table with a `type` / `role` column:

There's just one table with `id`, `user_id`, `token`, `created_at` and **`type`** (enum) - `type` can in this case be all sorts of access-type, in our case `api-session`, `email-verification` and `password-reset`. (Of course this could be improved in a way that a token will give general access to a specific thing)

Pros:

- It's just one table
- Can easily be extended without making it hard to use (I'll always be one table)

Cons:

- Another conditional where you'll have to check the type before looking for the token itself
- Can get confusing I guess as although it's only one table there are differences based on `type`

Is there a generally preferred way of doing this (I'm using [mariadb](https://mariadb.org) if that's important) / is there a third, better way of doing it? Or does it really not matter that much and I'm just overthinking it?

I tried to find existing schemes / db-designs but I couldn't find anything useful as there is afaik no name for this whole thing (please tell me I'm wrong and I just cannot search correctly).

Comment: Why not have a column for each of those tokens in the same table with the user information and their password?

Comment: @Dave that would result in much data-redundancy as for example, password-reset and email-verification are both barely used **and** the user should be able to have multiple web-sessions hence one single value wouldn't work :/

Comment: Why would there be more than one key for an API endpoint? There should be one per user IMO. And there isn't any redundancy for verification and reset .... the reset column can be a single byte that is true/false.

Comment: @Dave I mean, well want be logged into a web-page on more than one machine right? And I doubt that it's good practice to like ship the same session-key x times. In case the user logs out only the current session gets invalidated like on most pages. And also for security purposes there should be a token which can only be used to reset your password / verify email.

PS: Why did you delete your answer, I liked it and I'd agree :)

Comment: It wasn't I who answered. You didn't say logged in to a web page you said API endpoint which is very different. If your application needs to be secure enough for you to track sessions as you've described then you do not want people logging on to more than one machine at a time. A token for reset/validate yes, in which case there should be a token column and a true/false column for password and verify.